# is it possible to add new words to alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to add new words to alexa in such a way that alexa can understand it?

I'm trying to add the word EGMORE(pronounced as egg-more) but alexa is taking the input as ignore.

It is taking it as Egmore when the utterance statement is small, but when the statement is big, it is taking as ignore.

Example - the place is egmore(this works correctly, this is taken is egmore).

find the distance between egmore(this is taken as ignore) and sun.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the word recognitin in alexa skill interface is not possible. But you could try some things:

- In the app you can see your last commands. You could file a bug ticket and send feedback. Have you tried that?
- You could define the "egmore" as slot and define different utterances which should map to "egmore": [Entity Resolution](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/define-synonyms-and-ids-for-slot-type-values-entity-resolution.html) . Than later in your programmed backend you have to substitute this word back
- You could post your question in the official [Alexa forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/spaces/165/index.html) and hope that a amazon worker file a ticket for it